# MySQL: Key-Value vs. Null Columns for creating tables with unknown number of columns

Tags: mysql

I am designing a database which holds a lot of information for a user. Currently I need to store 20 different values, but over time I could be be adding more and more.

I have looked around StackOverflow for simular questions, but it usually ends up with the asker just not designing his table correctly.

So based of what I have seen around StackOverflow, should I:

1. Create a table with many null columns and use them when needed (this seems terrible to me)
2. Create a users table and a information table where information is a key-value pair: [user_id, key, value]
3. Anything else you can suggest?

Keep in mind this is for a MySQL database, so I understand the disliking for a Key-Value table on a relational database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, i am a bit confused by the question, but it sounds like you want to have lots of attributes for one user right? And in the future you want to add more??
Well, isn't that just have a customer_attribute_ref ref table of some sort, then you can easily add more by then inserting to the ref table, then in the customer table you have at least three columns : 1. customer ID 2. customer attribute ID 3. customer attribute value...

may be i missed your question. Can you clarify

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest 3.  A hybrid of 1 and 2.  That is, put your core fields, which are already known, and you know you'll be querying frequently, into the main table.  Then add the key-value table for more obscure or expanded properties.  I think this approach balances competing objectives of keeping your table width relatively narrow, and minimizing the number of joins needed for basic queries.

Another approach you could consider instead of or in combination with the above is an ETL process of some kind.  Maybe you define a key-value table as a convenient way for your applications to add data; then set up replication, triggers, and/or a nightly/hourly stored procedure to transform the data into a form more suitable for querying and reporting purposes.

The exact best approach should be determined by careful planning and consideration of the entire architecture of your application.

Comment: I will add another option to my list: 4. Just add the column to the user table with defaulting to null.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky isn't that the same as #1 ?

Comment: No no, add the columns as needed with the default value. #1 says to have a few unreserved columns. #4 means to have no unreserved columns.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky I don't understand the difference.  What do you mean by *unreserved*?  What difference does it make to the design whether you initialize the columns with a default value, or with null?

Comment: 'Unreserved' means existing but not used. The existing rows must have a value, I was just saying to set them to NULL. It seems you really don't know what I'm talking about. Your original answer was fine enough. Thank you.